# Warning when upgrading junrar: Symbol extractArchive is deprecated

Tags: java, scala, unrar

I'm using [junrar](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.github.junrar/junrar) 0.7 and am trying to upgrade to version 4.0.0, and in the process I am getting warnings about a certain method I am using to unrar a file to a destination directory. Here is my code (in Scala):

```
val rar = new File(archive)
val dest = new File(destination)
val extractArchive = new com.github.junrar.extract.ExtractArchive()
extractArchive.extractArchive(rar, dest)
```

However, my IntelliJ reports that extractArchive is now deprecated, and I'm wondering what is the correct way to do this now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the documentation for that deprecated method, which explains what you have to do:

```
     * @deprecated  As of release 1.0.2, replaced by { @link #Junrar.extract(final String rarPath, final String destinationPath) }
     *
     * @param archive rar file path
     * @param destination folder where the files will be extracted
     *
     * @throws IOException .
     * @throws RarException .
     */
    @Deprecated
    public void extractArchive(File archive, File destination) throws RarException, IOException {
        Junrar.extract(archive, destination);
    }
```

So basically, your code should now look like this:

```
val rar = new File(archive)
val dest = new File(destination)
Junrar.extract(rar, dest)
```